# Обрезание подчеркивания у ссылок при overflow:hidden

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Имеется меню навигации. Все элементы меню с `float:left`. Для того, чтобы блок под меню не "флоатился", самому меню прописываю `overflow:hidden`, но тогда обрезается подчеркивание у ссылок. Есть ли еще способы побороть это, кроме как добавление `padding-bottom:2px` (обычно задаю в em'ах, так как шрифт может меняться) для меню?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хм, мне кажется, padding-bottom в px приемлемое решение. Линия, подчеркивающая текст, не зависит от размеров шрифта - так что вполне подходят пиксели.

Answer (score 1):

`white-space: nowrap` контейнеру и тогда убрать overflow. Либо элементам `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Если будет nowrap то тогда пункты меню не будут вообще переноситься на другую строку, а пунктов может быть много и нужно как раз, чтобы они переносились. С display:inline-block та же история, что и с float:left.

Comment: Можно посмотреть код?

Answer (score -1):

> Для того, чтобы блок под меню не
> "флоатился", самому меню прописываю
> overflow:hidden

Попробуйте для этого сделать clear:both - это убивает "флоатинг"